# Javascript bind this to a function outside object

Tags: javascript, object, call, bind, apply

I have read about bind being used to access `this` inside a function outside the object but for some reasons I am not able to do that.

```
function test (len){
    return this.length - len;
}
var SETTINGS = {
     length : 21,
     trimmed: test.bind(this,5),
     x: function(){
        return this.length;
     }
};
SETTINGS.x(); // this is available.
SETTINGS.trimmed(); //len is 5 but this is Window.
```

May be it has something to do with my understanding of bind.

Comment: during defining `SETTINGS` object `this` points to `window`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because at the time you are binding `this` it points to `window` object. This is a little tricky, but in JS just because `this` is within an object it **doesn't automatically become the object**. It is more like: `this` **points to the window unless some rule is applied**.

What rule you might ask? From an amazing book series [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#determining-this):

> Determining this
>
> Now, we can summarize the rules for determining this from a function
>   call's call-site, in their order of precedence. Ask these questions in
>   this order, and stop when the first rule applies.
>
> Is the function called with `new` (**new binding**)? If so, this is the
>   newly constructed object.
>
> `var bar = new foo()`
>
> Is the function called with `call` or `apply` (**explicit binding**), even
>   hidden inside a bind hard binding? If so, this is the explicitly
>   specified object.
>
> `var bar = foo.call( obj2 )`
>
> Is the function called with a context (**implicit binding**), otherwise
>   known as an owning or containing object? If so, this is that context
>   object.
>
> `var bar = obj1.foo()` - that is why `SETTINGS.x();` works btw.
>
> Otherwise, default the this (**default binding**). If in strict mode, pick
>   undefined, otherwise pick the global object.
>
> `var bar = foo()` - your case

**In your case the default rule applies.**

Be aware of an ES6 [arrow functions](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/arrow-functions-vs-bind.html), as they bind `this` (just like `bind`) automatically.